# How to get all data from set

Tags: python, list, set

So, its my data in list:

```
[('AED', Decimal('3.67303')), ('AFN', Decimal('89.408409')), ('ALL', Decimal('118.735882')), ('AMD', Decimal('420.167855')), ('ANG', Decimal('1.803593')), ('AOA', Decimal('431.906'))]
```

And I did this but only for first element: `Currency: AED, Value: 3.67303`

```
 for key, val in query:
    return f'Currency: {key}, Value: {val}'
```

How can I do this for all?

Comment: too many values to unpack (expected 2) @Guy

Comment: No set in that code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return everything from a function create a new list with list comprehensions

```
def func():
    lst = [('AED', Decimal('3.67303')), ('AFN', Decimal('89.408409')), ('ALL', Decimal('118.735882')), ('AMD', Decimal('420.167855')), ('ANG', Decimal('1.803593')), ('AOA', Decimal('431.906'))]
    return [f'Currency: {key}, Value: {val}' for key, val in lst]
```

or use `yield` to create a generator

```
def func():
    lst = [('AED', Decimal('3.67303')), ('AFN', Decimal('89.408409')), ('ALL', Decimal('118.735882')), ('AMD', Decimal('420.167855')), ('ANG', Decimal('1.803593')), ('AOA', Decimal('431.906'))]
    for key, val in lst:
        yield f'Currency: {key}, Value: {val}'
```

another less explicit way to create a generator

```
def func():
    lst = [('AED', Decimal('3.67303')), ('AFN', Decimal('89.408409')), ('ALL', Decimal('118.735882')), ('AMD', Decimal('420.167855')), ('ANG', Decimal('1.803593')), ('AOA', Decimal('431.906'))]
    return (f'Currency: {key}, Value: {val}' for key, val in lst)
```

Output

```
for val in func():
    print(val)

Currency: AED, Value: 3.67303
Currency: AFN, Value: 89.408409
Currency: ALL, Value: 118.735882
Currency: AMD, Value: 420.167855
Currency: ANG, Value: 1.803593
Currency: AOA, Value: 431.906
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
from decimal import Decimal
a = [('AED', Decimal('3.67303')), ('AFN', Decimal('89.408409')), ('ALL', Decimal('118.735882')), ('AMD', Decimal('420.167855')), ('ANG', Decimal('1.803593')), ('AOA', Decimal('431.906'))]

for i in a:
    print(f'Currency: {i[0]}, Value: {i[1]}')

Currency: AED, Value: 3.67303
Currency: AFN, Value: 89.408409
Currency: ALL, Value: 118.735882
Currency: AMD, Value: 420.167855
Currency: ANG, Value: 1.803593
Currency: AOA, Value: 431.906
```

Answer (score 1):

Your return statement breaks the loop, so just the first element will get returned.

It looks like you want to print it in the console?!

Then just change the line to: `print('Currency: {key}, Value: {val}')`

When you want to do something else with it, please be more accurate, what you want to do.

Comment: what if i want to return my all data,not only first element?

Comment: When you want to return all data, then you must append all in a `list` and return the list.

Comment: @makim Your list **is** all of your data

Answer (score 0):

You could return a list of format strings then print them by unpacking that list. Like this:

```
from decimal import Decimal

query = [('AED', Decimal('3.67303')), ('AFN', Decimal('89.408409')), ('ALL', Decimal('118.735882')), ('AMD', Decimal('420.167855')), ('ANG', Decimal('1.803593')), ('AOA', Decimal('431.906'))]

def data(q):
    return [f'Currency={c}, value={v}' for c, v in q]

print(*data(query), sep='\n')
```

**Output:**

```
Currency=AED, value=3.67303
Currency=AFN, value=89.408409
Currency=ALL, value=118.735882
Currency=AMD, value=420.167855
Currency=ANG, value=1.803593
Currency=AOA, value=431.906
```